# Table with sticky header and sticky first column but content of first column to overflow under header - with CSS only

Tags: css

as the title say, I have a table with sticky header and sticky first column and I would like the first column to overflow under the header.
In the JS fiddle & example below, at the movement the first column overflows above the header.

How could I do this ? (without an external library if possible)

the js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/base_kh/oe9ytg2m/33/

```css
.table-responsive {
  height: 500px;
}

.table.calendar thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: pink;
}

.sticky-col {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  width: 6em;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table calendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">1</div>
            <div class="col">M</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">2</div>
            <div class="col">T</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">3</div>
            <div class="col">W</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">4</div>
            <div class="col">T</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">5</div>
            <div class="col">F</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">6</div>
            <div class="col">S</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">7</div>
            <div class="col">S</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">8</div>
            <div class="col">M</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">9</div>
            <div class="col">T</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">10</div>
            <div class="col">W</div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 1</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 2</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 3</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 4</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 5</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 6</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 7</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 8</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 9</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 10</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle gives 404 - I made you a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you right - just a simle adding of `z-index` to your thead css will do all the magic. So

```
.table.calendar thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: pink;
  z-index:3;
}
```

```css
.table-responsive {
  height: 500px;
}

.table.calendar thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: pink;
  z-index:3;
}

.sticky-col {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  width: 6em;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table calendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">1</div>
            <div class="col">M</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">2</div>
            <div class="col">T</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">3</div>
            <div class="col">W</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">4</div>
            <div class="col">T</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">5</div>
            <div class="col">F</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">6</div>
            <div class="col">S</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">7</div>
            <div class="col">S</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">8</div>
            <div class="col">M</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">9</div>
            <div class="col">T</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">10</div>
            <div class="col">W</div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 1</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 2</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 3</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 4</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 5</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 6</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 7</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 8</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 9</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky-col">
          <div>Title 10</div>
        </th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: ... can't. believe. this. THANK YOU !